# Custom class working like a using statement with curly braces

Tags: c#, design-patterns

Is it possible to create a class, or operator, that would work like **using** does?

Example:

```
using (IDataReader reader = cmd.ExecuteReader())
{
  while (reader.Read())
  {
    count++;
  }
}
```

Often we use the `using` statement to not have to handle post operations manually, like `dispose` and such.

I have in mind a couple of usage of this mechanic.
But I cannot figure out how to achieve this.

An example of actual implementation:

```
  MyClass mc = new MyClass();
  MyClass sub = mc.GoDown();
  //Do things on sub
  sub.GoUp();
```

What I would like it to be:

```
  MyClass mc = new MyClass();
  mc.GoDown {
    //Do things on sub
  } // GoUp
```

I know I could use a `try {} finally {}`.
I am just curious if there is a way to do what `using` is doing.

Edit:
I do know about the `IDispose` implementation.
I am just wondering if we can do what `using` does without `using`.

Edit #2:
Improved the example.

Comment: You can make a class implement `IDisposable` and just put the finally logic in it's `Dispose` method.

Comment: But that would require a **using** statement. My question, which might have not been clear enough, was about doing the same thing as **using** but without the **using**.

Comment: Your example is not clear - it looks like you're calling a constructor to a class. Can you provide a more concrete example of what you want to do?

Comment: Why would you create something like `using` when you can just use `using`?  What functionality do you need that you cannot get from `using`?

Comment: I have updated the example. I hope it will clarify things.

Answer (score 2):

Your class simply needs to implement `IDisposable` to support usage in a using block:

```
public class MyClass : IDisposable
{
    public void Dispose()
    {
        // Do your cleanup
    }
}
```

Then you can use:

```
using (var instance = new MyClass())
{

}
```

Do read [Implementing a Dispose method](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/standard/garbage-collection/implementing-dispose) on Microsoft Docs though.

Comment: I know about this. I was wondering if there was a way to do it without the **using** statement itself.

Comment: I think the question is more academic in nature - not about reimplementing `IDisposable` pattern but rather about creating a similar programming pattern to the one that happened to be used in the way the `using` statement functions in C#.

Answer (score 2):

Here's how you'd make the example work by passing in an `Action<MyClass>` to `GoDown` and `GoDown` will handle calling `GoUp` on `sub`.

```
public class MyClass
{
    public MyClass GoDown(Action<MyClass> doStuff)
    {
        var sub = new MyClass();
        //Whatever GoDown did to create a MyClass goes here

        try
        {
            doStuff(sub);
        }
        finally
        {
            sub.GoUp();
        }
    }
}
```

Then call it like this.

```
MyClass mc = new MyClass();
mc.GoDown(sub =>
{
    //Do things on sub
});
```

And `GoUp` will be called on `sub` even if there's an exception in the delegate you pass in.

Comment: That is an interesting implementation. Similar to @PiotrWolkowski solution but simpler. Thanks

Answer (score 1):

The closest construct to what you suggested I can think of would be a method that takes an object and `Func` or `Action` as an argument and if the object is of certain type - e.g. implements an interface, then performs the task.

Let's start with an interface:

```
public interface IMyWrapper
{
    void Do();
}
```

For simplicity I created a single example for an Action that does not take any arguments:

```
public class MyWrapper
{
    public static void MyWrapperMethod(IMyWrapper wrapped, Action doStuff)
    {
        try
        {
            doStuff();
        }
        finally
        {
            wrapped.Do();
        }
    }

    public static void MyWrapperMethod(object notWrapped, Action doStuff)
    {
        doStuff();
    }
}
```

IF you pass an object that implements `IMyWrapper` interface it will run the `Do()` method of the `IMyWrapper` interface, after performing what's in the `doStuff` action. Else it will just run the `doStuff`.

To invoke that run it like that:

```
MyWrapper.MyWrapperMethod(new object(), () =>
{
    Console.WriteLine("Do stuff");
});
```

This will only write "Do stuff".

Let's now create a class that impments the interface:

```
public class MyWrappedClass : IMyWrapper
{
    public void Do()
    {
        Console.WriteLine("I implement the wrapper.");
    }
}
```

and use it in the `MyWrapperMethod`:

```
var myWrappedClass = new MyWrappedClass();
MyWrapper.MyWrapperMethod(myWrappedClass, () =>
{
    Console.WriteLine("Do stuff");
});
```

This will print "Do stuff" and "I implement the wrapper". This is b/c the `MyWrapperMethod` will execute the `Do` method for us.

That's the closest to what `using` does I could think of.

Comment: Yeah, I considered something like that too. But it added too much complexity .

Comment: I would say, depends on how complex scenario you are handling. If the interface shows up a lot, or perhaps it's more than single interface that needs to be handled it very well may be worth the initial complexities to simplify the code everywhere else. But the usefulness will need to be considered on case by case basis. No simple answers here.